# Unable to install Ganache

Tags: visual-studio-code, installation, blockchain, truffle, ganache

Unable to install Ganache, because of Truffle certificate expired
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZAwx.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

First install Ganache CLI using CMD or Terminal  and then install Ganache GUI.
It worked for me.